# ERROR Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: node.js, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio, titanium-android

Working on android Titanium app, but I got the error building app on the android device

Titanium SDK Targeting 5.5.1.GA, (dont wanna use 6.x.x.GA)

below error, I am getting.

> Writing unmerged custom AndroidManifest.xml
>   [INFO] :   Packaging application: /Users/apple/Desktop/Titanium/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/apple/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/NBStore/build/android/gen" "-M" "/Users/apple/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/NBStore/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "/Users/apple/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/NBStore/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "/Users/apple/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/NBStore/build/android/res" "-I" "/Users/apple/Desktop/Titanium/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23/android.jar" "-F" "/Users/apple/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/NBStore/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview" "-S" "/var/folders/n5/rvsyx_zn7zj18tp7_nvh5xth0000gn/T/1171116-38126-xvmesk.s7mkl/res" "-S" "/var/folders/n5/rvsyx_zn7zj18tp7_nvh5xth0000gn/T/1171116-38126-1okeu7f.97uo/res" "-S" "/var/folders/n5/rvsyx_zn7zj18tp7_nvh5xth0000gn/T/1171116-38126-8lmck2.sraax/res"
>   2017-12-16T16:27:31.643Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
>   2017-12-16T16:27:31.644Z | ERROR  | Path must be a string. Received undefined
>   Path must be a string. Received undefined
>   [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

System setting

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.0

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 4294967296
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 8.9.1
  npm Version                 = 5.5.1
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.5.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/apple/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA
  Target Platform             = android
```

Please correct where i am wrong, spent too much time on this issue.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall node an reinstall, this work for me